# How to handle a name that includes an exclamation point (or other punctuation)?

Tags: punctuation, writing, proper-nouns

Certain brands, such as **Yahoo!**, insist that the exclamation is part of their name. In writing about such a brand or company, is the inclusion of the vanity punctuation right, wrong, or optional?

I would like my writing to be correct; however, of more concern with the average reader, I wouldn't want my writing to seem to be pandering.

Comment: Are they seven-year-olds living in England? {[The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2016/mar/07/children-use-exclamation-marks-department-education)}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems optional, considering that even [business article](http://www.businessinsider.com/yahoo-ma-chief-out-2010-12) talk about Yahoo, while introducing some facts at the end about "Yahoo!".

If your article is about the public corporation, you should use ***consistently*** one convention, preferably the one using the exact name of the company: "Yahoo!".

But "Yahoo" is also natural since:

- you won't find any punctuation in the host names: `www.yahoo.com`, not `www.yahoo!.com`
- at least, it won't wreak havoc in your word processor spell checker ;) See [Ignoring Punctuation in Names](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001834_Ignoring_Punctuation_in_Names.html) if you still have to use the '`!`'.

Comment: To be fair, `!` is not a valid domain name character, so it's impossible for Yahoo! to use it, though I'm sure they would if they could.

Comment: The rumor is that one early version of the DNS specification prohibited names from starting with a digit (that makes it much easier to tell a host name from an IP address -- just look at the first character), and 3COM madly protested, eventually prevailing. Now we look at the last character.

Answer (score 13):

The best way to deal with the vanity punctuation is as [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/12/01/yahoo_product_lay_offs/) do. Note "Related stories."

---

Edit (as requested) a sample of headlines from online newspaper The Register:

[Yahoo! wonks! brace! for! lay-offs!](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/12/01/yahoo_product_lay_offs/)
[Yahoo! buys! TV-sharing! startup! IntoNow!](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/04/26/yahoo_buys_intonow/)
[Yahoo! Buzz! Given! Mercy! Bullet!](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/04/18/yahoo_buzz/)
[Yahoo! to! offload! Delicious! as! early! as! next! week!](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/03/18/yahoo_delicious/)
[Yahoo! revenues! dip! 4! per! cent!](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/01/25/yahoo_fourth_quarter_earnings/)

You get the idea. Yahooexclamationmark's PR boss may feel a bit ambivalent.

Comment: That's excellent. I resent every time I sense that I'm being asked to put any punctuation in a corporate name other than an apostrophe. As a Joomla! developer, I spent a lot of time resenting this.

Comment: It's a bit late, I know, but could you include some quotes from the link? This being the internet, link rot happens, *especially* if you're depending on the "related stories" listed on the other site.

Comment: @Martha: Pleased to be of service.

Comment: Danke schön! (Still giggling at the exclamation marks, btw.)

Comment: Not to be rude, but what does this have anything to do with a valid answer?

Comment: I have always felt that el Reg has the right idea, with their mocking headlines. Sadly, they always refer to the company as "Yahoo!" in their articles.

Answer (score 4):

Some sites, will use *Yahoo!* while talking about the company, but others do not. For example, check this [CNN Money page](http://money.cnn.com/quote/quote.html?symb=YHOO) that refers to the company as Yahoo! Inc.

Answer (score 1):

From a legal standpoint, you want to use the the official trademark name that the company uses in naming itself. Check court documents to see what Yahoo prefers and use that.

Comment: Like you carefully don't, you mean?

Comment: Nobody is legally obliged to use the company's preferred form.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you should use the name as the company prefers it, but there's nothing to stop you mocking it gently.  If I am writing to somebody at one of those 'cool' companies that disdain capital letters and spaces, I make a point of addressing the envelope to 'johnrsmith, coolconsultancy': similar use of exclamation marks seems only fair to Yahoo!

Incidentally, there is a village in Devon called Westward Ho!; the punctuation is undoubtedly part of the name there.