# Using exclamation points as part of a brand name

Tags: punctuation, slang, business-language, brands

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle a name that includes an exclamation point (or other punctuation)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/how-to-handle-a-name-that-includes-an-exclamation-point-or-other-punctuation)

I am editing a text about a product whose name contains an exclamation point as the final glyph. I don't think that the exclamation point is being used to convey emphasis of any sort. It's my thinking that the inclusion of the glyph was purely visual gimmick--distinguishing it from the character of "exclamation point". What is the protocol for punctuating a sentence that ends with this product name? For example:

The greatest product ever is *MyProduct!*.

Since I believe the exclamation point to be a glyph and not a character, thus meaning it really isn't being used as punctuation, is ending with a period here appropriate?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to handle a name that includes an exclamation point (or other punctuation)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/how-to-handle-a-name-that-includes-an-exclamation-point-or-other-punctuation) and [others](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13493)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Several brand names use an exclamation mark](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1024&bih=581&tbm=isch&q=outrageous%20brand%20name&btnG=Search#hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=brand%20names%20with%20exclamation%20mark&pbx=1&oq=brand%20names%20with%20exclamation%20mark&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=273l582l0l1359l10l3l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1&biw=1024&bih=581), presumably to add "visual impact" to the name.

The website Yahoo (Yahoo!) makes use of it.  Throughout Yahoo's lengthy [Terms of Service](http://info.yahoo.com/legal/us/yahoo/utos/utos-173.html) the name is used with the accompanying exclamation mark.

This holds good especially if there's a TM or an encircled R next to the brand name. In this case, the style has been registered - better use the name as is, exclamation and all. 
A Brand Name is a special kind of proper noun, and it includes any and all quirky accoutrements. iPhone, for instance, begins with a lowercase i but this doesn't mean you don't/can't start a sentence with the word.

If the text you're working on is for the company that makes the product, it'd be simpler to just follow the brand guidelines. If it is a general text, see point 15 in Yahoo's terms of service, which uses a period after the word *Yahoo!*. This would be the ideal usage - as far as the company with the punctuated brand name is concerned.

In a general text that isn't paid for by the brand, you can hijack the exclamation at the end of the word to punctuate the entire sentence.

Comment: :-) The question linked in the comment cites the same example. Didn't see it till after I posted. *Consistency in use* makes sense, having looked at the replies to the Yahoo question.

Answer (score 1):

I would apply the same rule applied to quotes containing an exclamation point: The period is not used if a sentence ends with a quote that ends with an exclamation point, or a question mark.

> I said, "I love punctuation!"
>   She asked, "What time is it?"
>    I am the CEO of *ExclamationPoint!*

Comment: Yes, quite right.