# What is the correct way to punctuate sentences that end with proper nouns who also contain punctuation?

Tags: punctuation, sentence-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to handle a name that includes an exclamation point (or other punctuation)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/how-to-handle-a-name-that-includes-an-exclamation-point-or-other-punctuation)

Pardon the example usage, but given a proper noun that contains punctuation (e.g., the title of a show, *Yu-Gi-Oh!*), how would sentence punctuation be used?

> 1. Do you like to watch Yu-Gi-Oh!?
> 2. Yes, I watch Yu-Gi-Oh!.
> 3. I can't believe someone your age still watches Yu-Gi-Oh!!

Are these correct, or should they omit the additional punctuation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/how-to-handle-a-name-that-includes-an-exclamation-point-or-other-punctuation and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42120/using-exclamation-points-as-part-of-a-brand-name

Comment: For whatever reason, those questions didn't turn up in my search. :-\ Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newspapers often have trouble with this. For example, Yahoo! was a bit troublesome early on because they insisted their company name have an exclamation at the end of it. But most papers ended up taking the exclamation point off, as you can see in this New York Times' piece ([link](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/09/15/business/media/aol-yahoo-and-microsoft-are-said-to-reach-an-ad-deal.html?_r=1&scp=3&sq=yahoo&st=cse&gwh=54910334FB3DE5F4E70DEA37FE496DD9)).

Comment: Excellent! People who decide to make up names that violate basic rules of punctuation or capitalization, the backbones of writing, have to right to tell us how to write. Just adjust the name to what seems reasonable. We don't feel obligated to write Athens in Greek letters because the Greek government wants us to, do we? Nor do we write *Athini* or something like that to best match the Greek word in Latin letters. Outside databases, there is absolutely no need for exact character matches anyway; besides, several search terms can be grouped as aliases there anyway.

Comment: Not to mention the artist formerly known as prince

Answer (score 0):

Do the same as [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk/) and add additional exclamation marks for every other word.

For example:

- 2011: "[Kick! Bostock! out! too! demands! Yahoo! shareholder!](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/15/fund_manager_urges_ceo_yang_to_sack_yahoo_chairman/)"
- 2001: "[Yahoo! Hit! By! Power! Outage!](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2001/05/08/yahoo_hit_by_power_outage/)"
- 1998: "[Yahoo! profits! soar!](http://www.theregister.co.uk/1998/10/08/yahoo_profits_soar/)"