# Should you use a comma before the "Inc." in a company name?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Should you use a comma before the "Inc." in a company name?

**Xona Games, Inc.**

vs.

**Xona Games Inc.** (in this example, this is the official registration format)

?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6114/8019

Answer (score 5):

One should write the name of a company exactly as it was spelled (or misspelled) in the official registration.

Comment: Great answer.  A company name is a name and will have an official version.  It's like asking if you should use the hyphen in the name of a woman with a hyphenated name.  Yes.  It's her name.

Comment: Good point indeed. For me, that's Xona Games Inc. without a comma. Looks cleaner this way too.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the style guide you follow. There are lots of guides and they differ on many things. The Chicago Manual of Style says "no". However, if it's your company, do what you want. The style guides don't dictate how you should label your business. Just be consistent.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate on what consistencies their opinion is based on? For the record, I know I can do whatever I want, so perhaps I should reword the question. Feel free if you think this is necessary.

Comment: It's not their opinion. It's their decision to leave the commas out between "inc", "LLC", "Ltd" and a few others, as a rule, so that all writers of that style are on the same page.

Comment: Ok, so I was about to ask what consistencies is their decision based on, but, from what I understand, the decision is to create consistency. Do I have that right? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Use or don't use. Just be consistent in your usage.

Answer (score 2):

Page 134 from the Associated Press Stylebook 2013 reads, "Do not set off with commas".

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, the law is strict on this. If the comma appears in the papers of incorporation, it must be used in all legal transactions. Many lawsuits have been lost because the person or company filing suit left out the comma, or inserted it, against what was filed. Any attorney will explain this for you. I once had to fire a proofreader at my publishing company because he insisted on inserting the comma where it wasn't called for, even though I explained the law to him.